# How to categories results of a query based on date range

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query

```
Select PRODUCT_NAME, MIN(DATE_A), MAX(DATE_A), SUM(UNITS) FROM TABLES GROUP BY PRODUCT_NAME
```

Results

```
PENCILS      1/1/2015        3/15/2015          454
PENS         2/1/2015        3/15/2015          754
```

I would like to categories the query to result for pencils

```
0-30 days total units  - 201
31-60 days total units - 202
61-90 days total units - 51
```

Results could be in the following format

```
PRODUCT     DATE_FROM      DATE_TO      30 days   60 days   90 days
PENCILS     1/1/2015      3/15/2015     201         202       51
PENS        2/1/2015      3/15/2015     401         352       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:

```
with dates as (
  select product_name, min(date_a) date_from, max(date_a) date_to 
    from tables group by product_name)
select product_name, date_from, date_to,
    sum(case when date_from +  0 <= date_a and date_a < date_from + 30 
      then units else 0 end) d30,
    sum(case when date_from + 30 <= date_a and date_a < date_from + 60 
      then units else 0 end) d60,
    sum(case when date_from + 60 <= date_a and date_a < date_from + 90 
      then units else 0 end) d90
  from tables t join dates d using (product_name)
  group by product_name, date_from, date_to order by product_name
```

If you want more periods please add next columns.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ab48/1)

Comment: The result was as required.

Comment: I would like to add a few comments on this @Ponder Stibbons. If one is looking for average instead of sum, it is wise to use null in place of 0 sum(case when date_from +  0 <= date_a and date_a < date_from + 30 
      then units else NULL end) d30,

Comment: Nope. For average values please use [avg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions011.htm) function. Adding anything to null gives null.

Comment: Sorry I meant AVG(case when date_from + 0 <= date_a and date_a < date_from + 30 then units else NULL end) d30,

Comment: My concept on average was if you use 0, it is considered in the average but null is not.

Comment: Not sure why you consider this. (0+1+8)/3=3. (null+1+8)/2=4.5? OK. I will think about, but please remember our space for commenting here is limited. Please write on my mail address visible in profile.